# Node NPM error: Cannot find module 'write-file-atomic'

Tags: javascript, node.js, cmd, npm, installation

[image: Error]

I am trying to install packages using NPM, but this error still appears each time. And something for any operation like "init, start, install".

Comment: Are you getting this error when running your Node application or is it showing when you try to install other packages? Have you tried `npm install write-file-atomic` - and what error are you getting then?

Comment: This happened each time I use npm, even i tried to print the vision of npm this errors appears!

Comment: Can you confirm your `NODE_PATH` variable?Is this set to the correct path? If the error occurs with every `npm` command, then it might be an issue with installation. Check and confirm

Comment: Yes I can confirm the NODE_PATH and its in the correct path.

Comment: I think that something with the rights is messed up. Try to run it as admin or use 'sudo' for unix. I have this issue only when I'm installing packages globally.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all 
I solved the problem by delete everything related to NPM and NODE and re-install it again